# VB.NET escribir archivo txt está siendo utilizado por otro proceso

Tags: vb.net

El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo botsettings.txt porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso.

```
Private settingslocation As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory + "\botsettings.txt"       
Private Sub save_settings()
    Try
        If File.Exists(settingslocation) Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(settingslocation)
            File.Create(settingslocation)
        End If
        Dim writesettings As New System.IO.StreamWriter(settingslocation)
        With writesettings
            .WriteLine(mytextbox.Text)
            .Close()
            MsgBox("Settings saved!")
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

El problema es que el archivo si está siendo utilizado es por el mismo código, ni lo tengo abierto ni nada por el estilo, he probado cambiando el nombre al archivo y me da el mismo problema...

Lo que quiero hacer es no tener ese error y poder escribir en el archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Adrián, y ¿cuál sería tu pregunta?

Comment: y si esta siendo usado.. que esperas hacer? es problema de la arquitectura de windows no dejarte usar un archivo que esta siendo usado exclusivamente por otro proceso

Comment: si sigues el codigo paso a paso, y esperas entre cada instruccion, funciona correctamente?

Comment: no, en la linea: Dim writesettings As New System.IO.StreamWriter(settingslocation) salta el error

Comment: Agregas el error exacto a al pregunta?

Comment: disculpa, ya lo he agregado!

Comment: Los errores deben estar completos.. pero bue... y estas seguro que nadie mas lo esta usando en ningun lado?

Comment: no, si lo he intentado con otro nombre, como puedes ver en el código lo estoy creando desde 0 el archivo, ah disculpa ahora lo cambio de .message a .tostring